# Quoting the output of a backtick command

Tags: shell-script, quoting, command-substitution

I'm trying to run an expect script that runs a telnet session to automate the sending of an email, I'm trying to pass the contents of a file as a single argument to my script but when the backticks are interpreted the white space in that file are causing multiple arguments to be passed.

Here's my command...

```
runTelnet `cat test_results.txt`
```

Is there a way to quote the output of a backtick expression?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
runTelnet "$(cat test_results.txt)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
runTelnet "`cat test_results.txt`"
```

Enclosing the backticks in quotes will cause the results of the command to be passed to `runTelnet` as a single argument.